# Derivative of a normalized cross product

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I'm having some troubles solving the following problem:

I want to calculate the partial derivative (wrt. $\xi $ and $ \eta $ )  of a normal vector n on G1 and G2 by using the cross product. The normal vector reads:
$$\ n= \frac{G1\times G2}{|| G1\times G2||}$$

I started doing it for $ \frac{\partial n}{\partial \xi}$ and came to the point:

$$\ \frac{\partial n}{\partial \xi} = \frac{ \frac{\partial G1}{\partial \xi}\times G2 + \frac{\partial G2}{\partial \xi} \times G1}{||G1\times G2||} - \frac{(G1\times G2) \frac{\partial}{\partial \xi} 
( ||G1\times G2||)}{|| G1\times G2||^2}$$

Unfortunately I couldn't proceed, since I didn't come up with a solution for the partial derivative of the norm of a cross product $ \frac{\partial}{\partial \xi} 
( ||G1\times G2||)$. This is a 3D problem.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: In general, we have
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial \xi} \|f(\xi)\| = \frac {f(\xi) \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial \xi}}{\|f(\xi)\|} = 
\frac {f(\xi)}{\|f(\xi)\|} \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial \xi},
$$
where $a \cdot b$ denotes a dot-product